# LINQ - nested SelectMany as Query Syntax

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq

I have the following working LINQ expression which I want to convert to query syntax to try and aid readability

```
Dim statements = itemGroups.Select(Function(ig) ig.LinkedItems.SelectMany(Function(i) RefreshItem(i, GetTable(i.EventKey, targetTable)).Statements) _
                                                              .MergeUpdates) _
                           .SelectMany(Function(u) u)
```

As you may be able to see I have nested IEnumerables, but I want flatten and apply the MergeUpdates function to those nested lists prior to flattening the whole thing.

Thus far I have

```
Dim sl = From ig In itemGroups
         From i In ig.LinkedItems
         From s in RefreshItem(i, GetTable(i.EventKey, targetTable)).Statements
         Select s
```

but I'm not sure quite how to flatten and merge the nested IEnumerables using query syntax.

Appreciate any help.

(BTW - I'm happy with either VB or C# syntax)

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that what you need is:

```
var statements =
    from itemsGroup in itemGroups
    from linkedItemStatements in
        //here goes a nested query
        (from linkedItem in itemsGroup.LinkedItems
            let table = GetTable(linkedItem, targetTable)
            select RefreshItem(linkedItem, table).Statements)
        .MergeUpdates()
    from statement in linkedItemStatements
    select statement;
```

However, I don't see how it is more readable. I use a rule of thumb while working with LINQ: if your inline query is too complex, separate it to different methods. The only exception is working against `IQueryable` API's which don't accept external code, such as LINQ to Entities.

So I would do something like:

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Statement>> GetMergedItemStatements(
    ItemGroup itemsGroup,
    DataTable targetTable)
{
    var statements =
        from linkedItem in itemsGroup.LinkedItems
        let table = GetTable(linkedItem, targetTable)
        select RefreshItem(linkedItem, table).Statements;

    return statements.MergeUpdates();
}
```

and then:

```
var statements =
    from itemsGroup in itemGroups
    from linkedItemStatements in GetMergedItemStatements(itemsGroup, targetTable)
    from statement in linkedItemStatements
    select statement;
```

Which looks good using extension methods as well:

```
private static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<Statement>> GetMergedItemStatements(
    ItemGroup itemsGroup,
    DataTable targetTable)
{
    var mergedStatements = itemsGroup
        .LinkedItems
        .Select(linkedItem =>
            RefreshItem(linkedItem, GetTable(linkedItem, targetTable)).Statements)
        .MergeUpdates();

    return mergedStatements;
}
```

and:

```
var statements = itemGroups
    .SelectMany(itemsGroup => GetMergedItemStatements(itemsGroup, targetTable))
    .SelectMany(mergeStatements => mergeStatements);
```

So, pick the option you think is most readable.